# What is the best way to implement my control

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I need to have many different buttons like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DetailSectionButton}" Click="Button_Click_5">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Image Grid.Column="0" Stretch="None" 
                             Margin="0 0 10 0"
                             Source="../Assets/icons/info.png" />
      <TextBlock Text="info" Grid.Column="1"
                                   Margin="0 10 0 0" />
   </Grid>
</Button>
```

Each button have your own `Image.Source`, `TextBlock.Text` and Button.Click event handler.

What is the way to implement this button if all that I want to use this button is something like this:

```
 <MyButton ImageSource="../Assets/icons/info.png" Text="info" Click="Button_Click_5" />
```

Do I need to create UserControl or it will be enough to use some Template or Attached property ?

Comment: When you want to have an `ImageSource` property in your Button, you would typically create a custom control which derives from Button, and add an ImageSource dependency property, that is used in the custom control's Style (in Generic.xaml). An alternative would be to add a Setter for the `Template` property in the "DetailSectionButton" Style, with a ControlTemplate that uses the Button's `Tag` property for `Image.Source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least 2 ways of doing this.

First is to inherit from Button, extend it with your ImageSource Dependency property and bind to it inside DataTemplate.

Another way to do this is to create ImageSource attached property, and bind to it inside DataTemplate as below:

```
public class Config
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ImageSource", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (Config), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public static void SetImageSource(DependencyObject element, ImageSource value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static ImageSource GetImageSource(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ImageSource) element.GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
    }
}
```

Here is the data template and button:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0"
               Source="{Binding Path=(s:Config.ImageSource),
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
               Stretch="None" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="0 10 0 0"
                   Text="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Button Click="Button_Click_5" 
        Content="Info"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"
        s:Config.ImageSource="media_stop_red.png" />
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Just extend button control with ImageSource dependency property and create default style for it, like below:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSource", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (MyButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof (MyButton);
    }
}
```

Style and button itself:

```
    <Style TargetType="s:MyButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="s:MyButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                               Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}"
                               Stretch="None" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Margin="0 10 0 0"
                                   Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <s:MyButton Content="Info" ImageSource="..\media_stop_red.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I have not AncestorType.  Is it code for Windows 8.1 XAML ? If it is not, what is the alternative ?

Comment: I miss that this is windows 8.1, hence i don't predict lack of AncestorType. In this case you need to use variant from my answer. I'm going to edit my answer with that approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. What does it mean 's:' in the TargetType? Is it the namespace of MyButton class? Do I need to write `TargetType="MyNamespace:MyButton" ?

Comment: exactly, s is the namepace. and yes you need to define it like this:       **xmlns:s="using:SomeNamespace"**, and than write before using your control, not only in target type, but everywhere in your xaml. e.g.    **<s:MyButton** Content="Info" ImageSource="..\media_stop_red.png" />,                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="**s:MyButton**">

Comment: Thanks, it works. Only one questions left. All buttons change change the background and foreground color when the mouse over them.  I think it is defined in theme.  But our new button doesn't change the colors when the mouse over it.  How can I fix it? Do I need to add this behaviour in Style ?

Comment: Exactly. This style is default for your new control(button). You can retrieve default button style for your button using blend and combine with above one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new usercontrol, it has xaml and code behind.
Now change in xaml usercontrol to Button and in code behind change the inherited clase from usercontrol to Button too.

now add the contenet of the button

Then add the dependency properties with an event that set the value for the controls